# File configuration for using nested modules with alias in python

Tags: python

I have a python package structured like this:

```
.
├── Module
│   ├── subModule1
│   │   ├── file1.py
│   │   └── file2.py
│   └── subModule2
│       ├── file3.py
│       └── file4.py
└── main.py
```

Where `main.py` is my top level script and it will use a module called `Module` where, for code organization, I have split it into two sub modules with several functions in files `file<N>.py`.

In `main.py` I would like to use the module as:

```
import module as m
```

And use the functions from the submodules as:

```
m.sm1.foo() # foo is a function from submodule1
m.sm2.faa() # faa is a function from submodel2
```

How can I defined the `__init__.py` to do this?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the following hierarchy:

```
.
├── main.py
└── Module
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── subModule1
    │   ├── file1.py
    │   ├── file2.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    └── subModule2
        ├── file1.py
        ├── file2.py
        └── __init__.py
```

One solution can be:

`Module/__init__.py`:

```
from . import subModule1 as sm1
from . import subModule2 as sm2
```

`Module/subModule1/__init__.py`:

```
from .file1 import foo
from .file2 import bar
```

`Module/subModule2/__init__.py`:

```
from .file1 import faa
from .file2 import baz
```

`Module/subModule2/file1.py`:

```
def faa():
    return "faa"
```

`main.py`:

```
import Module as m

print(m.sm2.faa())
```

Output:

```
faa
```

Comment: thanks! I was really struggling with this!